# How to retrieve value from another mongoose collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm attempting to find() in one collection and concatenate that value to the correct object returned by subsequent find(). However I cannot guarantee the value retrieved in the first find() will match the index . How do I ensure the first value (Boolean) is attached to the correct instance of the second find()?

What I have so far is to use the indexes of the first condition but it may not match if an instance has been removed

My Model:

```
let Instance= new Schema({
  imgName: String,
  offer: String,
  brand: String,
  desc: String,
  keywords: Array,
  loc: String,
  location: {
    type: {
      type: String, // Don't do `{ location: { type: String } }`
      enum: ['Point'], // 'location.type' must be 'Point'
      required: true
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
      required: true
    }
  },
  categories: Array,
  userId: String,
  active: Boolean,
  stockPic: String,
  startTime: Number,
  endTime: Number,
  range: Boolean
});

mongoose.model('Beams2', Instance);

let LikesSchema = new Schema({
  userId: String,
  likeId: String,
  categories: Array,
  public: Boolean
});

mongoose.model('Likes', LikesSchema);

//My query:

exports.findAllLikes = function(req, res){
  Likes.find({'userId': req.body.userId}, function(err, results) {
    let likeIds = results.map((currentValue, index, array) => {
        return currentValue.likeId;
    });

    let statusArr = results.map((currentValue, index, array) => {
        return currentValue.public;
    });

    Instances.find({'_id': { $in: likeIds }}, function(err, favs){
      if (err) return console.log(err);

      let newArr = [];
      favs.forEach(function(element, i) { 
        //console.log(statusArr[i]);
        let post = element.toObject();
        post.public = statusArr[i]; //need to guarantee correct value
        newArr.push(post);
        console.log(post);
      });

      return res.send(newArr);
    });

  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this is how you could achieve what you are looking for:

```
exports.findAllLikes = function(req, res) {
    Likes.find({
        'userId': req.body.userId
    }, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error while fetching likes: ', err);
            return res.status(500).json({
                Error: 'Error while fetching likes.'
            });
        }
        const likeIds = results.map(({
            likeId
        }) => likeId);

        Instances.find({
            '_id': {
                $in: likeIds
            }
        }, (err, favs) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error while fetching likes: ', err);
                return res.status(500).json({
                    Error: 'Error while fetching Instances.'
                });
            }
            let newArr = [];
            favs.forEach((elem) => {
                let post = elem.toObject();
                const likeDoc = results.find(({
                    likeId
                }) => likeId === post._id.toString());
                post.public = (likeDoc && likeDoc.public) ? likeDoc.public : '';
                newArr.push(post);
            });
            console.log(post);
            return res.status(200).send(newArr);
        });
    });
};
```

You shouldn't ever play with indexes for mapping stuff, until and unless you are sure that you have same length arrays.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply however the public attribute returns blank in all instances even though the Likes collection has Boolean: true

Comment: Can you try to debug and find out what values you are getting in 'likeDoc'?

Comment: likeDoc returns undefined in all instances

Comment: const likeDoc = results.find(({
    likeId
}) => {
    console.log('likeId is: ', likeId);
    console.log('_id is: ', post._id);
    return (likeId === post._id);
}); can you try this and check what values you're getting in console

Comment: discovered the problem.  The post._id required converting .toString().

const likeDoc = results.find(data => data.likeId === post._id.toString());

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197349/discussion-between-mohammed-amir-ansari-and-user601935).

Comment: Mohammed Amir Ansari That's correct the _id field is type ObjectId so needed converting to string in find() query. Thanks for your help